# Can Doctrine hydrate my entity with a custom scalar values (e.g. aggregate, CASE result, etc) out of the box?

Tags: php, doctrine-orm, doctrine

If I have a Querybuilder instance and apply something like this:

```php
$queryBuilder->addSelect("
   CASE
      WHEN c.modifyStamp > c.createStamp THEN 'draft'
      ELSE 'published'
   END AS state
");
```

then, on using `getResult`, I will get something like this:

```
[
   0 => [
      0 => \App\Entity\Test instance,
      'state' => 'draft'
   ],
   1 => [
      0 => \App\Entity\Test instance,
      'state' => 'published'
   ]
]
```

Which is not really ideal (but I know is expected, by default). To my Entity, I tried adding this:

```php
private $state;

public function getState(): string
{
   return $this->state;
}

public function setState(string $state)
{
   $this->state = $state;
}
```

...in the hope that the hydrator could see a property (or setter) of the right name, populate it just like any other property, and then just give me a regular array of objects back (pure), rather than the array of arrays (mixed). If you used Symfony serializer for example, you could comfortably take an array of data and apply it to an object with properties the same name as your array keys.

`getScalarResult` will bunch all the fields in each record together, but I don't want to work with arrays here. I'd like an array of objects, just like a regular `getResult` would give me if i DIDN'T use the statement above.

I guess I could loop through the results (when in the 'mixed' form) and invoke the setters directly, or use `getScalarResult` and somehow hydrate manually, but these options just seem clunky. So:

1. Is there a built in option/config/hydrator/trick I'm missing? OR..
2. Can/Should I create a custom hydrator for this case? OR
3. Should I just suck it up, loop the data, apply the dangling extra fields, and return the data in the expected format?

Thanks :)

**EDIT**: Using PHP post-search isn't viable, because the `draft` field (example above)  also needs to be part of a set of search filters (via a UI that also has pagination - so all needs doing in the DB and not as after-the-fact PHP code.)

Comment: Just for info, Doctrine completely ignores all methods (including the constructor) when hydrating an entity.  Doctrine uses reflection to instantiate the object and then directly set the property values.

Comment: @Cerad yeah, that's caused a few headaches in the past :D but in this case, I set my property up like any other, just to cover all bases anyway of what i'd expect/need down the line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## 1. MySQL (>= 5.7) Generated columns

```
namespace Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

#[ORM\Entity]
class Test {
    #[ORM\Id]
    #[ORM\GeneratedValue]
    #[ORM\Column(type: 'integer')]
    private int|null $id = null;

    #[ORM\Column(type: 'integer')]
    private int|null $modifyStamp = null;

    #[ORM\Column(type: 'integer')]
    private int|null $createStamp = null;

    #[ORM\Column(
        type: "string",
        insertable: false,
        updatable: false,
        generated: "ALWAYS",
        columnDefinition: "VARCHAR(9) AS (CASE WHEN modifyStamp > createStamp THEN 'draft' ELSE 'published' END)"
    )]
    private string|null $state = null;
}
```

```
$queryBuilder = $entityManager->createQueryBuilder();
$queryBuilder->select('c')->from('Entity\Test', 'c');
echo '<pre>';
var_export($queryBuilder->getQuery()->getResult());
echo '</pre>';
```

See: https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/2.14/reference/attributes-reference.html#column and: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/create-table-generated-columns.html

## 2. Custom Hydrator

(Ugly but doesn't need MySQL support)

The only thing I can find to make it work in PHP is an "ugly" hack on the hydration code. And this hack is made uglier by some of the internal conventions of Doctrine's `ObjectHydrator`.

```php
use Doctrine\ORM\Internal\Hydration\ObjectHydrator;

class CustomHydrator extends ObjectHydrator {

    private function remapScalars($mixedResultRow) {
        $object = $mixedResultRow[0];
        $remainingScalars = [];
        foreach($mixedResultRow as $name => $value) {
            if ($name == 0) {
                continue;
            }
            $setter = 'set' . ucfirst($name);
            if (method_exists($object, $setter)) {
                $object->$setter($value);
            } else {
                $remainingScalars[$name] = $value;
            }
        }
        return count($remainingScalars) == 0 ?
            $object :
            array_merge([$object], $remainingScalars);
    }

    protected function hydrateRowData(array $row, array &$result) {
        parent::hydrateRowData($row, $result);
        $latestKey = array_key_last($result);
        $latestItem = $result[$latestKey];
        if (is_array($latestItem)) {
            $result[$latestKey] = $this->remapScalars($latestItem);
        }
    }
}
```

The entity is pretty much how you had it:

```php
namespace Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

#[ORM\Entity]
class Test {
    #[ORM\Id]
    #[ORM\GeneratedValue]
    #[ORM\Column(type: 'integer')]
    private int|null $id = null;

    #[ORM\Column(type: 'integer')]
    private int|null $modifyStamp = null;

    #[ORM\Column(type: 'integer')]
    private int|null $createStamp = null;

    private string|null $state = null;

    public function setState(string $newState) {
        $this->state = $newState;
    }
}
```

And I use the following in the controller:

```php
$entityManager->getConfiguration()->addCustomHydrationMode(
    'CustomHydrator',
    'CustomHydrator'
);

$queryBuilder = $entityManager->createQueryBuilder();

$queryBuilder->select('c')->from('Entity\Test', 'c')->addSelect(
    "CASE WHEN c.modifyStamp > c.createStamp
        THEN 'draft' ELSE 'published' END AS state"
);

echo '<pre>';
var_export($queryBuilder->getQuery()->getResult('CustomHydrator'));
echo '</pre>';
```

## 3. Database Views

If all else fails, you could use a MySQL view and make your entity map to that. That way the view does the `CASE WHEN` and from your entity's point of view it's just another column.

Comment: Yeah, create/modifyStamp are ordinary timestamps and already regular entity properties. Creating a `getState` method would indeed work for cases where i'm just grabbing details after the fact, but these things are used as filters for lists (via the UI) so need to be done in the DB to work well together with pagination, etc too. For the most part, that's fine - but doing the extra stuff to hydrate one field (for later display purposes) when the target object already has a property & a getter ready to accept it - just seems like I've missed a feature somewhere...

Comment: 1 and 2 are certainly both viable options without too many significant changes. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You could use the Doctrine **[postLoad](https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/2.14/reference/events.html#reference-events-post-load) event** to add a "real" property to your entity and use it as is

```
/**
 * Test
 *
 * @ORM\Entity
 * @ORM\HasLifecycleCallbacks
 */

class Test
{

    ...

    private $state;

    public function getState(): string
    {
       return $this->state;
    }

    /**
     * @ORM\PostLoad()
     */
    public function initState()
    {
        $this->state = $this->modifyStamp > $this->createStamp ? 'draft' : 'published';
    }
}
```